# view controllers using storyboard

Tags: ios5, storyboard, viewcontroller

i am trying to switch between two view controllers using storyboard. I create a modal seague by control-dragging (on buttons) from 1st view controller to 2nd, and then from the 2nd to the first.

So whenever I click on a button in 1st VC, it takes me to the 2nd VC. This time when i click the button on second VC, does it take me back to the original instance of the 1st VC or it creates a new instance?

If it takes me to the same instance, and user had written some data in some textfields, is there anyway to retain that on screen? (I might want to save them in some variables, and since the program will return back to the same instancem i'll be able to get the variables back)

If it doesn't take me to the same instance, is there any method to do so?

I tried making an instance of 2nd VC and using self.navigarionController push...(instance) but this doesn't swtich the controller.

If i do this pushing using the storyboard, and i do pop in my 2nd VC, it doesn't get popped either.

(and i would also couldn't understand the difference between push,modal and custom seagues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the modal segue from VC1's button to VC2, but not the reverse one.  When the VC2's button is tapped, call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` to return to where you were.

If you used a push segue instead, you would call `popViewControllerAnimated:` to go back but that only works if you have your view controllers managed by a `UINavigationController`.

You can think of push as a way of stepping through a sequence of related scenes while modal is something that's a bit out of the normal flow of the application.  (That's not a firm rule but it's a starting point for deciding which way to go.)  For 'custom', you write the segue code, so you decide what happens.